# CMD and supervisord

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, docker, supervisord

I am trying to get docker ENTRYPOINT or CMD to startup supervisor when the image is run.

This is the last line in my `Dockerfile`:

```
CMD ["service supervisor start"]
```

This isn't working. I get the error:

```
Error response from daemon: Cannot start container eb3eeb404462343680fec5af4c5a6372046713a3ccaa2893c9f4a0a9eda97753: [8] System error: exec: "service supervisor start": executable file not found in $PATH
```

Comment: Do you have systemd installed and running in the container?

Comment: @EEAA I haven't done any additional tweaking of the OS so I'm guessing it's still using upstart. I just need supervisor to be started when the image is run.

Answer (score 0):

Worked using the following:

```
CMD ["/usr/bin/supervisord"]
```

https://docs.docker.com/v1.8/articles/using_supervisord/